# Generalizing Euler's Polyhedral Formula for Graph Embeddings in Higher Dimensions.

Tags: graph-theory, simplicial-stuff, combinatorial-geometry

In the plane, Euler's Polyhedral formula tells us that $V - E + F = \chi$, where for graph embeddings we have that $\chi = 1$. Alternatively, we can think of a graph embedding as a simplicial $1$-complex embedded in the plane.

My question is about if there exists a straightforward generalization of the value of the Euler characteristic to higher dimensions. In particular, for a graph embedded in 3-space, or equivalently a simplicial 2-complex or simplicial 3-complex embedded in $\mathbb{E}^3$, is there a simple expression that defines the Euler characteristic as a constant value, as there is for the plane? (namely $\chi =1$).

Thank you!

EDIT: I am aware that there is a general formula for $\chi$ if you know the number of faces of a given dimension, I am looking to determine those faces by knowing what the Euler characteristic is from external information.

Comment: According to wiki, the Euler's characteristic $\chi = v_0 - v_1 + v_2 - v_3 + \cdots + (-1)^d v_d$, where $d$ is the dimension, $v_i$ is the number of $i$-faces. When $d=2$, the formula reads $\chi = v_0 - v_1 + v_2 = V- E+F$. Is this what you need?

Comment: How I want to use this, is to determine some of the $v_{i}$'s without knowing that information. I'm looking for the value of $\chi$ in more generality. For graph embeddings in the plane $\chi =1$, for graph embeddings (or simplicial 2-complexes, simplicial 3-complexes) in $\mathbb{E}^3$, is there also a simple answer?

Comment: The Euler characteristic isn't constant in higher dimensions. However, it has many equivalent characterizations and can be computed in lots of different ways; the Wikipedia article should have more details.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I am interested in the "lots of different ways" you mentioned. I have already read the wikipedia article thoroughly. Do you happen to know if given the conditions that a simplicial $3$-complex $\mathcal{K}$ in $\mathbb{E}^3$ (for now, I want to generalize to simplicial $k$-complex) is homogeneous and connected, if there exists some characterization of the Euler characteristic of $\mathcal{K}$ in terms of the number of vertices of $\mathcal{K}$?

Comment: @Samuel: the number of vertices shouldn't determine the Euler characteristic in general. What do you mean by homogeneous?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: "A homogeneous (pure) simplicial $k$-complex $\mathcal{K}$ is a simplicial complex where every simplex of dimension less than $k$ is a face of some simplex $\sigma \in \mathcal{K}$ of dimension exactly $k$."